# Are there any programs like family echo that I can use to map mathematics?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software, data-analysis, network

Family echo is an online program that allows one to make a family tree, if nothing is clicked it shows most of the family tree as it is, but if one clicks a name one can see clearly all the ancestors and descendants of that person, and can read information about them. Is there any software like that that can be used to make a more general graph/network? 
Is there any fairly easy to use software that I can use to map out mathematical definitions, axioms and theorems such that it is clear what depends on what, and I can find out more information about "Theorem 8a" by merely clicking on it?

If possible I'd like it to be able to display the entire, massive, graph if I wanted to see it.

I've tried visgraph, but it doesn't have the interactivity I'd like.

I'm not entirely sure about the tags, so I apologise if I'm using some incorrectly.

Edit: I'd also like to be able to label the vertices, if possible. And I'm fine with the software not being free, if it's not too expensive and is useable enough.

Comment: The Stacks Project implements something like what you are talking about; I don't know if that implementation will be useful to you, but you could take a look. See here: http://math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=3439

Comment: The force directed versions of the graphs look very much like what I'd like to create...but I'd like to create one of these myself...is there any software that would let me do that?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea on the technicalities. But the Stacks Project is completely open-source, so you should be able to read through the documentation to find how it was done, and obtain the software yourself. Good luck!